# Why did a crazy blob chant “One of us, gooble-gooble” at me?

Tags: the-end-is-nigh

In Arid Flats 6, there is a skeleton you can talk to who hints to the location of a secret area.

> Shhhhh... There are others close by. Crazies who believe in what they call THE ASCENSION. They hide just out of view. Some are above, some below. Don’t try and find them, and definitely never speak to them.

[image: Skeleton in Arid Flats 6]

On the same screen, there is a small tunnel in between the floor spikes. Jumping down leads to an underground area labeled ???.

After traveling further down, I found an area which had a Mega Tumor (+5 tumors) and a strange blob person behind a wall. When talked to, he says:

> One of us, one of us!
>   Gooble-gooble gooble-gooble!
>   One of us, one of us!

**Why did this crazy blob chant “one of us” at me? What does this have to do with “The Ascension”?**

[image: Crazy blob chanting “one of us”]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9C4uTEEOJlM&t=18s

Comment: That must have been freaky... or it would've been if you'd seen the movie.